# Java: Replacing the values in an array and shifting the elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, shift

So I've been tasked with completing this program for my AP Computer Science class:

> Write the code that takes an array of doubles and moves all the values
>   greater than the average to fill the array to the left. Any values
>   less than the average that haven't been written over should be set to
>   0. First calculate the average and store it in a variable named average.
>
> Example:   The array [1.0 , 1.0, 3.0 4.0 ], the average is 2.25 would
>   be transformed to [3.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0]

```
public class Array {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    double[] arr = {
      1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0
    };
    double average;
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
      sum += arr[i];
    average = sum / arr.length;


    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

      if (arr[i] >= average)
        arr[i] = arr[i];
      else if (arr[i] < average) {
        arr[i] = 0.0;
        arr[i] = arr[i];
        for (int t = i + 1; t < arr.length; t++) {
          if (arr[i] >= average)
            arr[i] = arr[i];
        }
      }


    }
    for (int y = 0; y < arr.length; y++)
      System.out.println(arr[y]);
  }
}
```

and the output is:

```
0.0
0.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

I've been working on this for a few hours and still can't get the desired output which should be : 3.0 4.0 5.0 0.0 0.0

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What do you believe `arr[i] = arr[i]` does, and why do you believe it does anything at all? If you have to move a value from one place to another, don't you think the indexes need to be .... you know .... *different*? --- *Hint:* You need two index variables.

Comment: `arr[i] = arr[i];`?

Comment: Do it in two step; set to zero; shift the values.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class RearrangeArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         double[] arr = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0};
         double[] newArr = new double[arr.length];

         double sum = 0.0;  
         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
              sum += arr[i];
         double average = sum / arr.length;

         System.out.println("average = " + average);
         int n = 0;
         for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
         {
            boolean check = compare(arr[i],average);
            if(check)
            {
                newArr[n] = arr[i];
                n++;
            }
         }

         for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
         {
            System.out.print(newArr[i] + " ");
         }

    }
    public static boolean compare(double key, double average)
    {
        if(key >= average)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second step make two indexes: current index `i` and index of the place to fill `j`

At every i-step: if value at current index is larger than average, copy it into j-th element and increment `j`

I hope that the last step with zero-filling after the last `j` is simple enough